# Will using new constants break my android app?

Tags: java, android

I'm checking the orientation of a screen inside a view using:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

New versions of Android provide with more orientation states so I was thinking on using a switch with all the states I want to handle.

```
switch (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation) {
    case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
    case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT:
    case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
    case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE:
}
```

Now, will this break the application on old devices? Given that some of the constants are new for API 9+? I'm not sure because I'm not sure how constants (`final static`) are treated by the compiler. Are they inlined or referenced? I would think that if they are inlined there should be no issue with this method.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, will this break the application on old devices?

Not if you use them the way you are. The Java compiler will replace the symbols with their numeric equivalents at compile time.

However, you cannot get at those values via reflection on older devices, though that would be a rather unusual technique.

Comment: I was investigating compat code on Android doc and yes, they use this same method to detect versions. Makes sense that constants are inlined :)

Comment: I love it when optimizations have beneficial side effects.

Answer (score 0):

No , extra case will not break your application because

1. Changes will add extra case at compile time
2. At Runtime this case will determined.
3. It is just like an extra condition.